# Why AD users not auto login to portal

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I appologise to asking the same question but none of them solved my problem.

I created a portal in ASP.NET Web Form App 4.5 Framework

```
I have

 1. IIS 7.5 on MS Server 2008 R2
    -Windows Authentication (All others are disable)
    -DefaultAppPool v4.0

 2. MS Server 2008 R2 (Saved on active directory)

 3. Active Directory

 4. Web.Congif file with lines below
    - <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    - <identity impersonate="false"/>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>

 5. Clients(Users) are on the same AD.
```

Here is my scenario; When user enters myServerIP:PortNumber on browser,I want to user auto login to my portal without windows user name and password credential popup.I also check the user name cross AD if there redirect to Default.aspx, if not redirect to NotAllowed.aspx.

We have two different MS Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 on it. 
Let's name them IIS_X and IIS_Y.

We had a portal which codded a few years ago on IIS_X. IIS_X has the features written above. Users in my company can access the this portal without windows username and password popup window. So it works great.

Here is the problem: 
I published my portal to IIS_X, it promps windows popup to user one time and I write my windows username and pass then I access the portal.
But when I published my portal on IIS_Y (It has the feature written above),It promps four times. I write my name and my site opens but it promps three more times.

My question is : How can I solve this problem and let the user to access my portal without windows login promp.

Any help will be appriciated.

Here is my web.config file.

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>  

    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="29696"/>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

    <assemblies>
              <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>




    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" >
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

  </system.web>



</configuration>
```

Comment: Share the details of the web.config file; just a short version can't explain the behaviour!

Comment: config file has added. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question please.  First you have this paragraph:  "We had a portal which codded a few years ago on IIS_X. IIS_X has the features written above. Users in my company can access the this portal without windows username and password popup window. So it works great."  THEN, you follow that with this:  "Here is the problem: I published my portal to IIS_X, it promps windows popup to user one time and I write my windows username and pass then I access the portal."  My confusion is, do users experience a pop-up for authentication or not on IIS_X?  Then I can try to help.

Comment: Please add the 'authentication' and 'iis' tags to your question.